# Find all next elements with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="foo">One</li>
  <li class="bar">Two</li>
  <li class="bar">Tree</li>
  <li class="bar">Four</li>
  <li class="foo">Five</li>
  <li class="bar">Six</li>
  <li class="bar">Seven</li>
</ul>
```

and I have JS code like this:

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
   $(this).allNext('.bar');
});
```

How can I select all elements that are after .foo and have class bar.

Comment: I believe you want nextAll() http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
   $(this).nextAll('.bar');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

beside nextAll may be you want to know about nextUntil() .. it will select all .bar until the next .foo

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
   $(this).nextUntil('.foo').css('background','red');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrz5Leou/1/)